# How to push a page without bottom bar from inner page?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have implemented [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57627826/8276524) for nested navigation.

After that, from an inner page, I need to push a page without bottombar.There are some pages where I don't need the bottom bar to show. Do I need to start another Navigation stack? Its back button should also work as expected.

Simple Navigator.push() persists the bottombar. Navigator.pushNamed() seems not working.

Comment: if its a page without a bottombar there is no need for it to be nested.

Comment: @Henok I need to have some pages without bottom bar shown to be pushed from a page inside the base page.

Comment: Yes you can directly push them since the purpose of the nested page is to share the bottombar and you don't need it for these pages, at least try it and comment the results.

Comment: @Henok I have tried it. The bottombar persists too. There are some pages where I don't need the bottom bar to show. How to achieve this. Simply pushing with Navigator.push() don't work.