# Make nested navigator widget wrap child in Column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can I achieve this where a nested `Navigator` widget in a `Column` wraps the child content.

[image]

This crashes the app

```
 Column(
    children: [
       Text("First Text"),
       Navigator(
         key: _navigatorKey,
         initialRoute: widget.setupPageRoute,
         onGenerateRoute: _onGenerateRoute,
     ),
       Text("Second Text"),
    ],
 ),
```

with error

```
'package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart': Failed assertion: line 720 pos 12: 'constraints.biggest.isFinite': is not true.
```

but adding a `Flexible` around the Navigator doesnt respect the flex and it just expands.

```
    Column(
            children: [
               Text("First Text"),
               Flexible(
                child: Navigator(
                  key: _navigatorKey,
               initialRoute:widget.setupPageRoute,
                 onGenerateRoute: _onGenerateRoute,
             ),
),
               Text("Second Text"),
            ],
         ),
```

[image]

Any ideas on how this can be solved? Thanks in advance

Comment: may be this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48098085/nesting-routes-with-flutter

Comment: Thanks @Abhijith I dont have a problem with the way the navigation route works, only how it fits with the rest of widget around it. Which is not what the link asnwered.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55716230/how-to-do-nested-navigation-in-flutter

Comment: Still not, unfortunately. That link talks about how to do multiple nested navigation with bottom bar. Still more about how to do navigator routing,  not about how the Navigator itself sits in the layout.

Comment: Hi! @Bolaji did you find any solution to that? I'm also actually facing the same issue but In my case navigator is wrapped with CustomScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Before the [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14803) got fixed, you can wrap [IntrinsicHeight](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html) outside of the Navigator.

You only need to be careful with the notice in the document:

> This class is relatively expensive, because it adds a speculative
> layout pass before the final layout phase. Avoid using it where
> possible. In the worst case, this widget can result in a layout that
> is O(N²) in the depth of the tree.

```
Column(
  children: [
    Text("First Text"),
    IntrinsicHeight (
      child: Navigator(
        key: _navigatorKey,
        initialRoute:widget.setupPageRoute,
        onGenerateRoute: _onGenerateRoute,
      ),
    ),
    Text("Second Text"),
  ],
)
```